# Show the difference between two columns from two different tables (comparison table)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with the same structure and almost identical content. The main difference is that one value column may differ from the 'equivalent' one in the second table. On top of that, one record may appear in one table, but not in the other.

My tables:

**Table1 (idA, valueA, valueB, valueC (nullable), valueX)** 
**Table2 (idB, valueA, valueB, valueC (nullable), valueY)**

Desired result:

**Table3 (valueA, valueB, valueC, valueX, valueY)**

Preconditions:

- 'id' is a primary key and can differ in the two tables
- 'valueC' is the only column that can have a *null* value. However, the value will be the same in both tables.
- If a record appears in Table1 but not in Table2, 'valueY' shall be *null*
- If a record appears in Table2 but not in Table1, 'valueX' shall be *null*

Example:

Table1
1 | 1001 | 2001 | 3001 | 100.0
2 | 1002 | 2002 | 3002 | 95.0
3 | 1003 | 2003 | (null) | 113.0
4 | 1004 | 2004 | 3004 | 75.0

Table2
23 | 1001 | 2001 | 3001 | 100.0
24 | 1002 | 2002 | 3002 | 94.0
25 | 1003 | 2003 | (null) | 116.0
26 | 1005 | 2005 | 3005 | 32.0

The desired result should be:

Table3
1001 | 2001 | 3001 | 100.0 | 100.0
1002 | 2002 | 3002 | 95.0 | 94.0
1003 | 2003 | (null) | 113.0 | 116.0
1004 | 2004 | 3004 | 75.0 | (null) 
1005 | 2005 | 3005 | (null) | 32.0

I think I have come up with a solution but it is extremely slow and I am not sure if this really is the easiest way to do this.

```
SELECT valueA, valueB, valueC, valueX, valueY
FROM (
    (SELECT t1.valueA, t1.valueB, t1.valueC, t1.valueX, t2.valueY
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
        ON t1.valueA = t2.valueA 
        AND t1.valueB = t2.valueB 
    WHERE t1.valueC = t2.valueC OR t1.valueC IS NULL OR t2.valueC IS NULL)
    UNION
    (SELECT t2.valueA, t2.valueB, t2.valueC, t1.valueX, t2.valueY
    FROM Table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
        ON t1.valueA = t2.valueA 
        AND t1.valueB = t2.valueB 
    WHERE t1.valueC = t2.valueC OR t1.valueC IS NULL OR t2.valueC IS NULL)
    );
```

I hope someone can come up with a more 'elegant' solution. As a side note, I am using an Oracle DB. Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: if pk can differ between two tables, how do you match records i.e.,  how can you determine if/when "one record may appear in one table, but not in the other"

Comment: For my purpose it is enough to match the records based on values A, B, and C (the example here is simplified, my actual table has 7 columns that match). So if A, B and C match we can assume it is the same record. If one of them doesn't, it's a different record. So, if you have ABC values in table1 but no match in table2, it's missing from table2.

Comment: then add a key on columns A, B, and C.  Sounds like this might be a "natural key".  If you can't, do this due to duplicates, then it is not true that you can "assume they are the same record"

Comment: I suppose you can look at it as a "natural key", with the exception that C can be _null_. The other problem is that I'm not allowed to alter the tables as this is how they are defined by my client and used in the project.

Comment: Can you add an index ? If so, add a unique index. You can do this on a composite key including nullable attributes, and this will prevent duplicates in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gives desired output. I don't know if it's more elegant, but is shorter for sure ;-)

```
select valueA, valueB, nvl(table1.valueC, table2.valueC) valueC, valueX, valueY 
  from table1
    full join table2 using (valueA, valueB)
  order by valueA
```

---

BTW your query gave only 4 rows, without `1004 | 2004 | 3004 | 75.0 | (null)`, probably your `where` should be:

```
where t1.valueC = t2.valueC OR t1.valueC IS NULL or t2.valueC IS NULL
```

instead of

```
WHERE t1.valueC = t2.valueC OR (t1.valueC IS NULL AND t1.valueC IS NULL)
```

**Reworked query**

```
select a, b, nvl(t1c, t2c) c, x, y
  from (
    select nvl(t1.valueA, t2.valueA) a, nvl(t1.valueB, t2.valueB) b, 
        t1.valueC t1c, t2.valueC t2c, valueX x, valueY y
      from table1 t1 
        full join table2 t2 on (t1.valueA = t2.valueA and t1.valueB = t2.valueB
          and ( t1.valueC = t2.valueC or (t1.valueC is null and t2.valueC is null) ) )
        )
  order by a, b, c
```

Comment: I think this may be the answer. It's definitely much shorter and 5 times faster than my query. And you're also right about my where clause, I think I did a mistake there (I've modified the question with your correction). The odd thing is that while your query returns 6438772 records, mine returns 6879424. I'm hoping this is due to another issue in my query that I cannot seem to see at the moment.

Comment: The differences appeared due to misunderstanding on valueC comparison. Your last comment in main post changed things a little. So I modified query, and I think it works according to all conditions. It produces different results in columns valueX and valueY than yours if you add row (5, 1006, 2006, 3006, 101) to table1 and (27, 1006, 2006, null, 201) to table2, but I think you can't take these values from non matching rows.

Comment: Also if you now change valueC in added row in table2 from null to 3007, then my query gives 7 rows in result, yours - 5 rows. I do that because if rows do not match on ABC then we list them both not joined.

Answer (score 0):

Create  table c as (Select * from table a minus select * from table B) Union (Select * from table b minus select * from table A)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this doesn't work as it also joins on the ID and the valueX and valueY columns, which may have different values in each table. Also it doesn't juxtapose the last two columns, which is what I need.

Comment: And if you use my query but select less columns?